# Comparing Dates in java using equals

Tags: java, date

**UPDATE**I have an instance in my class `java.util.Date shippingDate` which I need to compare whether it is equal to current date or not.

```
java.util.Date shippingDate ;
Calendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
shippingDate=g.getTime();
if(shippingDate.equals(new Date()))
{
System.out.println("Match found");
}
```

`Equals` is overridden in Date, so it should execute the sysout.But its not printing anything.

PS#I am not allowed to use Joda Time library.

UPDATE- Is there any other way to compare `shippingDate` with current Date. I don't want to hardcode the current date using `SimpleDateFormat`. It has to be generated from system.

Comment: @libik That's in the `Date` class.

Comment: Just print `new Date()` back to back, and you will get the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28%29) gives a clue (emphasis mine):

> `public Date()`
>
> Allocates a `Date` object and initializes it so that it represents **the time** at which it was allocated, **measured to the nearest millisecond**.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `Date` object, it takes the current time of the system, so both dates actually differ in the milliseconds passed between lines

```
Calendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
```

and

```
if(shippingDate.equals(new Date()))
```

Answer (score 0):

have you noticed that you have two lines and at `line 1` you get calendar object and you compare the same with date object at `line 2`, understand that there is millisecond difference between execution time of both two so it would never be same.

```
java.util.Date shippingDate ;
Calendar g = new GregorianCalendar(); //line 1
shippingDate=g.getTime();
if(shippingDate.equals(new Date())) //line 2
{
System.out.println("Match found");
}
```

*The result would never be equal if you try to compare two different objects created in multiple statements.*

---

**Addressing to your question in update**:
get time in milliseconds using `shippingDate.getTime()` and then to compare this with system time use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or you can also use `System.nanoTime()` **but the result would never be same**